# Saving an Element's Index to a Variable

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables

I'm new to Ruby (and programming in general) and have been reading a ton of docs, how-tos and SO questions to try to find an answer to this problem but no luck so far.

I have an array of integers and I'm trying to save one of the object's integers to a variable to later delete that object from the array. What I have so far:

```
array = [3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 9]
objToDel = array[3]
array.delete_at(objToDel)
array
```

This deletes "1" in the array... I want it to delete "2" instead. I know this happens because having the variable point to array[3] points it to "2" instead of the actual third element in the array. I have tried the slice method as well to no avail.

So, is it possible to get a variable to equal an element's index instead of its content? Is this possible without turning the array into a hash?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just assign the index to the variable:

```
index = 3
array.delete_at(index) # => 2
array # => [3, 5, 1, 6, 9]
```

You could also use the `delete` method to remove the object directly.

```
object_to_delete = 2
array.delete(object_to_delete) # => 2
array # => [3, 5, 1, 6, 9]
```

Note that this deletes all instances of the object in the array, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it in your words, try this:

```
array = [3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 9]
objToDel = 3
array.delete_at(objToDel)
array
```

Good luck.